# No sube mi app realizada con Sails

Tags: javascript, nodejs, postgresql

Muestra el siguiente mensaje al intentar iniciar mi app en modo dev.

Incluyo las dependencias (tomado del package.json):

```
"dependencies": {
    "@sailshq/connect-redis": "^3.2.1",
    "@sailshq/lodash": "^3.10.3",
    "@sailshq/socket.io-redis": "^5.2.0",
    "async": "2.0.1",
    "grunt": "1.0.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.5",
    "sails": "^1.0.2",
    "sails-hook-grunt": "^3.0.2",
    "sails-hook-orm": "^2.0.0-16",
    "sails-hook-sockets": "^1.4.0",
    "sails-postgresql": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@sailshq/eslint": "^4.19.3"
  },

*Mensaje de Error:*

C:\Datos\Cursos\Sails\Tfotos\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:456
  throw new Error("Unknown authenticationOk message type" + util.inspect(msg));
  ^

Error: Unknown authenticationOk message typeMessage { name: 'authenticationOk', length: 23 }
    at Connection.parseR (C:\Datos\Cursos\Sails\Tfotos\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:456:9)
    at Connection.parseMessage (C:\Datos\Cursos\Sails\Tfotos\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:375:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Datos\Cursos\Sails\Tfotos\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:132:22)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:297:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:272:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:213:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

La app se conecta con PostgreSQL y uso flash también. Me comentan que información adicional es necesario incluir para su ayuda.

Gracias

PD: Estamos aprendiendo.

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx a SOes. Por favor, ve a [edit] tu pregunta y añade el listado de dependencias que estás usando en tu proyecto

Comment: Hola Alfabravo, esta actualizado con las dependencias. Gracias estoy atento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actualiza salis-postgresql. La [versión 1.0.1](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-postgresql) es de hace 4 años y posiblemente no soporte los algoritmos que usa postgresql >10 para hacer autenticación segura.

Comment: Gracias Alfabravo ya funcionado